# iMacros extracting POS from a search

Tags: web-scraping, imacros, extract

I am trying to work out how to extract the POS of a piece of text, and then use the extracted value to click a link based on the extracted information as part of a web scraping imacro. All the links on this page have the same text and are identified by a number in a different column of the table. For example, link A1 is in TD1, but the unique identifier is in TD2. To work out the link POS I'm adding 4 to the unique number POS and then dividing by 6.

The code I have so far is this, but when the imacro runs it is unable to extract the position using the search function.

```
SEARCH SOURCE=TXT:{{number}} EXTRACT=POS
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
ADD !VAR1 4
SET !VAR1 EVAL("!VAR1 / 6")
TAG POS=!VAR1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:align-left
```

Is there a way I can modify this code to click the link based on a unique number in a different cell, or a different way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using relative positioning for this scenario:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:{{number}}
TAG POS=R-1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:align-left
```

Comment: How are you setting R in this?

Comment: I'm not. R is not a variable, but rather signifies that the position is 'R'elative to the previously tagged item. In this case, since the value after R is negative, it instructs iMacros to tag the first link that appears prior to the previously tagged table cell containing the unique number you are looking for.

http://wiki.imacros.net/V7_Relative_positioning